# Calculate running total of active items

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate the running total of the `Quant` field below, but for the dates before the End Date.

For example, in the first row, we have `End Date = 01-03-2019` and `Quantity = 10`.

This quantity should not be considered on rows where `InvoiceDate >= 01-03-2019`.

[image]

So, I've tried a lot of stuff, but nothing seems to be working.

For example:

```
Active =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Table1[Quant]),
FILTER(
ALL(Table1[InvoiceDate]),
Table1[InvoiceDate] < MAX(Table1[EndDate])
)
)
```

And other DAX functions like ALLEXCEPT, and etc.

Expected output: 10, 14, 11, 16.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this (We must operate with SELECTEDVALUE -> value on this certain row):

```
running = CALCULATE( sum('run'[Quant]), FILTER(ALL(run), run[InvoiceDate] < SELECTEDVALUE(run[EndDate]) && run[EndDate]<= SELECTEDVALUE(run[EndDate]) && SELECTEDVALUE(run[InvoiceDate]) < run[EndDate] ))
```